# Print with BufferedGraphics using PrintDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a BufferedGraphics called backbufferGraphics and I want to print out the content in that buffered by using a PrintDialog, this is my code but it's not work:

```
private print()
{
        printDocument1.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
        printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        printDialog1.AllowSelection = true;
        printDialog1.AllowSomePages = true;
        printDialog1.ShowDialog();
}
void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    DrawToPrint(e.Graphics);
}
private void DrawToPrint(Graphics _Gd)
{
    backbufferGraphics.Render(_Gd);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you have first to set your buffergraphics in a image and after you will print image:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap();

int X = e.X - bmp.Width/2;
int Y = e.Y - bmp.Height/2;
// créer et initialiser le BufferedGraphics
BufferedGraphics bg =
BufferedGraphicsManager.Current.Allocate(this.CreateGraphics(),
ClientRectangle);
Graphics g = bg.Graphics;

g.Clear(SystemColors.Control);
g.DrawImage(bmp, new Point(X, Y));

bg.Render();
g.Dispose(); 
bg.Dispose();
//save bmp as file
```